# Need a little guidance with coding a button in a database workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I created a database in excel and worksheets that need to be copied and populated with information from a certain record from the database. I need a new workbook file to be opened with the individual's name on the filename and the workbook filled with the copied sheets and the information from the one record transferred over as well.

I am really new to using excel with VBA and am in need of assistance.

```
Private Sub Create_Plan_Click()

Dim UserFilename As String
Dim FullName As String

UserFilename = Combo_Title & Txt_FirstName & Txt_MiddleInit & Txt_LastName & Combo_Suffix
FullName = Combo_Title & " " & Txt_FirstName & " " & Txt_MiddleInit & ". " & Txt_LastName & " " & Combo_Suffix


Unload Choose_User

Meal_Cat_Form.Show

End Sub
```

Instead of showing Meal_Cat_Form, I want to copy the record along with other sheets in the database file and create a whole new workbook with the copied sheets and the info from the record chosen.

Answer (score 0):

This is more a prompt aimed at helping not an answer

Step 1 - Add-in info for where the data can be found

```
Private Sub Create_Plan_Click()

Dim UserFilename As String
Dim FullName As String
Dim dbSrcRow as long, dbSrcSht as Worksheet  ' These 2 Added

UserFilename = Combo_Title & Txt_FirstName & Txt_MiddleInit & Txt_LastName & Combo_Suffix
FullName = Combo_Title & " " & Txt_FirstName & " " & Txt_MiddleInit & ". " & Txt_LastName & " " & Combo_Suffix

' You also need to provide info as to where the data base record is
  Set dbSrcSht = "dbSheet"  ' You need to edit this
  Set dbSrcRow = 123        ' and this too
' Done

' I've swapped these next 2 lines around
' seems you need to carryout the copying before you loose/unload the data
  Meal_Cat_Form.Show  ' This will become the copy routine not a form
  Unload Choose_User
' Done

End Sub
```

Step 2 - Add-In info about which sheets need copying

```
' You also need to provide info as to which sheets need to be copied
  Set Shts2Copy = "Sht1,Sht2,Sht3"  ' You need to edit this
' Done
```

Finally - You need to create a new workbook and fill-in the info, then save it